# Captcha image verification: in C#.net and asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, captcha

How can I have Captcha image verification using asp.net forms?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A couple of things to look at:

- [reCAPTCHA .NET library](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/aspnet)
- [BotDetect](http://captcha.biz/asp.net-captcha.html?gclid=CI2u2-WDnKACFQkulAodgCSYdQ)

That was after a couple of minutes of searching - I'm sure you can find more.

Comment: +1 Damn you Mr Skeet,  you beat me to the punch.

Comment: reCAPTCHA .NET library is perfect library

but 

BotDetect ASP.NET CAPTCHA Free Trial Version

Comment: I am using BotDetect now on a new project. I chose it because it has no external dependencies, supports audio, and has multiple locale support. Full source available for $600.

Answer (score 3):

I have used this one first:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/CaptchaControl.aspx

But I've had massive spam problems by bots. Using ReCaptcha works perfect so far.

Answer (score 2):

this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/CaptchaControl.aspx will do great...

Comment: use reCapthca it is alot more secure.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I heard a friend hacker that captcha gives information to x companies that generated text at x time will be y and in this way they can spam...

Answer (score 1):

First of all Down load the MSCaptcha.dll from net
import that dll in toolbar and also add references in your Bin folder
In aspx file write the following Code

```
<cc1:CaptchaControl ID="CaptchaControl1" runat="server" 
                                     CaptchaBackgroundNoise="Low" CaptchaLength="6" 
                                     CaptchaHeight="60" CaptchaWidth="200" 
                                     CaptchaLineNoise="None" CaptchaMinTimeout="5" 
                                     CaptchaMaxTimeout="240" FontColor="#529E00"/>
<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text="Verification Code *" style="display: inline-block;width: 200px;line-height: 1.8; vertical-align: top; font-size: 12px;font-weight:bold;"></asp:Label>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtcaptcha" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="325px" style="border: 1px solid #900;"></asp:TextBox>
```

and in code behind file write

```
CaptchaControl1.ValidateCaptcha(txtcaptcha.Text.Trim());
     if (CaptchaControl1.UserValidated)
                {
                    lbierror.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                    lbierror.Text = "Valid";
                }
                else
                {
                    lbierror.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    lbierror.Text = "InValid Captacha";
                }
```

I hope 
this will work